# Handling Variables in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I Wonder if there is a better way (cause I'm feeling this is kinda "bad style") to store/alter values in Haskell:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do

  var <- return 3
  var <- if (...)
              then
                return (var + 3)
         else
           return (var - 3)

  (...)

  return ()
```

Comment: Actually you do not alter variables at all, you create a *new* variable with a *closer* scope, but this would fail dramatically for loops.

Comment: `let var = if (...) then 6 else 0`...? If that's not satisfactory, you should maybe modify your motivating example to show why.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to deal with changing variables in Haskell is with functions and recursion. To “change” the value of a variable you compute the new value and call some function with it. Then the function called will get that new value as it’s argument. Often this is a recursive call. Example with factorial below.

Imperative Pseudocode:

```
def factorial(n)
  a=1
  for i = 1 to n
    a = a*i
  return a
```

Translated to Haskell:

```
factorial n = go 1 1 where
  go a i | i <= n = go (a*i) (i+1)
  go a i | i >  n = a
```

Notice that we replace the mutation of variables with a recursive call. Here is factorial in idiomatic Haskell:

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

Often one doesn’t really need values of variables to change at all.

Finally one should note that you aren’t actually changing the value of the variable `var` because your code is doing something like:

```
return 3 >>= \var ->
(... return (var +3)) >>= \var ->
..,
```

So you’re just doing what I described above in a very roundabout unidiomatic way.